# Primary tabs display differently for different roles?

Tags: 8, navigation

In my Drupal 8 site (using the Seven theme), the primary tabs navigation are displaying differently for different roles. See screenshots below.

It would appear that for the limited Editor role, it's showing the tabs in some sort of space saving '...' dropdown menu (all the other tabs are hidden underneath the '...').

The browser windows are the same size and there is clearly plenty of room for all of the tabs as you can see in the Admin view.

What's going on here? How can I make the tabs on the Editor role look like they do on the Admin role?

Here's how it looks for the Admin role (good):
[image]

Here's how it looks for a limited Editor role (bad):
[image]

Comment: This is just the way that the seven theme styles the tabs for smaller screen sizes. If you don’t like it, you can create a new admin theme (using seven as a base) and change how they’re styled.

Comment: Have you tried Claro as an admin theme?  Seven is very old (been around 10+ years since Drupal 7), and efforts for improving the admin UX are now targeting the Claro theme.

Comment: In contrib, there's also [Gin](https://www.drupal.org/project/gin), which is built on top of Claro by the developers who worked on Claro and has even more nice features like dark mode.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is known thing with the Seven theme where if the browser is zoomed in, this collapsed tabs view will trigger. Here is more info:

[Tabs may not display correctly in seven theme if browser zoom is set](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3143105)

> Per several comments this is occurring when the browser zoom function
> is in use. Display works as expected when browser zoom is set to 100%.

Resetting browser zoom to 100% solves issue... temporarily anyway. Once the user zooms in/out or has their browser's default zoom set to anything other than 100%, the collapsed tab view will be shown.

Seeking a permanent fix!